# Why is the chart button missing when trying to create a chart using Easychart?

Tags: 8, charts

I have chart content type and chart content.

But when I try to add content I do not see the chart button, as shown in this image also:

[image: my problem image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) support request "[Installation on Drupal8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2670906)". It contains varioous hints about what might be the cause of your issue, such as in these comments in it:

- nr 3: You need to install embed & entity_embed to get the chart buttons.
- nr 8: I ... didn't have [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module installed.
- nr 8: It appears to look for ec.min.js. The Easychart library that drush installed for me didn't have ec.min.js , but copying ec.full.min.js to ec.min.js makes it all work

**Note**: I added the hyperlink here for the [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) (it's the commonly used one, there is no Easychart specific variation of it ... at least not that I'm aware of).

Comment: Charts Libraries API is different than other libraries?? because i already have the libraries module.

Comment: Check my updated answer to address your prior comment. But please EDIT your question to add an hyperlink to the module you're using, which I bet is the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module, and for sure not the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module (of which I'm a co-maintainer, which is why I'm sure about that).

Comment: thank u,, but i was used Easy chart module

Comment: OK @dilanarslan , but please **EDIT** (repeat: **EDIT**) you question to clarify that. There are dozens of charting modules, and **you** must say, in your question, which one it is that you're using. And include an hyperlink to that module in your question also.